# Straight edgeloop

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, edges, 3d-manipulator

I recently moved to blender from maya to give a try.
I followed feew guides and videos to have an idea how it works and makemy first 3D model of a weapon. Now i have the edge loop i made to have like a small spikeblade on one side and i dont know how to make it straight. I tried by using the move and shift+z but nothing.

[image]

Any idea how can i make it?

Comment: So you want the selected vertex at the same level as the others in the horizontal edge?

Comment: Can you just select the edge loop, press S, Z, then type 0 to give it a z scale of 0?